# How to get values from sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I want to get the username from another table using the id from current table.

```
$sql = "SELECT product_name,product_category,product_image_url,product_proposed_user_id 
FROM product_list";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr>
     <td>". $row["product_name"]."</td>
     <td>
       <a href=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>Remove</a>
     </td>
     <td>
      <a href='edit-product.php'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Edit</a>
     </td>
   </tr>";}
```

Here I am getting the details from table. I also have user id in this query, but what I want to do is I want to refer the user id to `users` table and get the username for that id and print the value

How can I do this? How can I use sub-query to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I dont see where you are executing your query string, your code should be like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT product_name,product_category,product_image_url,product_proposed_user_id   
       FROM product_list";
$result =$mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["product_name"].  
              "</td><td><a href=''><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>  
               Remove</a></td><td><a href='edit-product.php'>  
              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Edit</a></td></tr>";
        }
```

Here is a fix for your query(get user details):

```
$sql = "SELECT p.product_name,p.product_category,p.product_image_url,  
        p.product_proposed_user_id,u.user_name   
FROM product_list p, user u   
WHERE p.product_proposed_user_id = u.user_id ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` with user table:

```
$sql = "SELECT product_name,product_category,product_image_url,  
               product_proposed_user_id,u.user_name   
        FROM product_list pl   
        INNER JOIN users u on u.id = pl.product_proposed_user_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is actually a join to the users table (to get the names):

use this (you may need to replace the "users" table name and "first/last_name" columns per your particular case):

```
SELECT product_name,product_category,product_image_url,product_proposed_user_id,
users.first_name, users.last_name
FROM product_list
LEFT JOIN users 
ON product_list.product_proposed_user_id = users.user_id
```

Then in the PHP code use the first name and last name as needed.